# I want to redirect a user in Next without using <Link>. React Router has useNavigate(), so does Next Router have anything similar?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

I want to redirect users in NextJS similar to how you can use `useNavigate()`. `<Link />` is not good enough for this, because I want the user to be immediately redirected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you would be looking for the [`useRouter`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#userouter) hook to access the `router` object and issue an imperative navigation action.

Example:

```
const router = useRouter();

...

router.replace(targetInAppUrl);
```

See [router.push](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerpush) or [router.replace](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerreplace) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

For those that are facing issues

Instead of
`import { useRouter } from "next/router";`

Use

```
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
```

The rest stays the same